# Adapter submitList not adding new items inside LiveData observer

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-listadapter

I have the following code that gets info from LiveData from my Room DB -

```kotlin
    private fun initAdapterData() {
        adapter = FriendsListAdapter(requireContext())
        binding.friendsRecyclerview.setAdapterWithItemDecoration(requireContext(), adapter)

//        val testList = mutableListOf<FriendModel>()
//        for (i in 0..15) {
//            testList.add(FriendModel("Alon Shlider", 0))
//        }
//        adapter.submitList(testList)

        viewmodel.getAllFriends().observe(requireActivity(), Observer { userList ->
            val friendsList = mutableListOf<FriendModel>()
            userList.forEach { userModel ->
                friendsList.add(
                    FriendModel(userModel.firstName.plus(" ").plus(userModel.lastName), 0))
            }
            friendsList.forEach {
                Log.d("friend", it.toString())
            }
            lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                adapter.submitList(friendsList)
            }
        })
    }
```

For some reason, calling submitList inside the observer does not add the items to the list.

I have tried to add fake test items before the observer and it worked, and I have logged the model info before calling my submitList method and it printed valid information.

I also tried to wrap the call to submitList with a coroutine for Main dispacher, thinking it is related to the callback not being in the main thread or something like that but still no result.

What is it that I am missing? everything looks fine but data is not being added to my RecyclerView.

Comment: notify the adapter using `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after submitting the list. I think it will work

Comment: Nope, did nothing. 

All notify functions are redundant using AsyncListDiffer (ListAdapter), because this is the main feature of it compared to just using RecyclerView.Adapter class. It calculates the differences and notifyies using the relevant function.

Comment: Have you assign your adapter to RecyclerView and then after doing submit list?

Comment: Just did that and it worked. You can comment and I will approve, but I want to know first why does it require re-assigned of the adapter when in any other place it does not?

Comment: once you assign your adapter to recyclerView in oncreate method after that you can submit your list from anywhere.

Comment: This is exactly what I did and it seems like it's not true. I could submit a list from anywhere, execpt when inside livedata observer which required me to re assign the adapter.

Comment: can you please post your all code here so I can get an idea about it

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to assign your adapter to RecyclerView and then submit the list.

```
recylerView.adapter = adapter
adapter.submitList(friendsList)
```

Comment: As I sayed - this solved my issue, but I wanted to know why does it require me to re assign the adapter. 

At any other place it does not.

Comment: once you assign your adapter to recyclerView in oncreate method after that you can submit your list from anywhere without assign again.

Comment: I am having the same exact issue and i've already done recylerView.adapter = adapter in onViewCreated. I am still having this issue. Can you please help

Comment: What exact error you are getting please post it  here